# jQuery UI: Droppable ('drop' event, tolerance: touch )  bug in safari (mac)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, safari, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-droppable

I am not able to solve the following problem:

> The below code works in all browsers of **mac** as well as windows, except that it
>   **works partially on macs safari(5.1.5)**.
>
> **Note:** It works on windows safari(5.1.5).

This is the **basic structure**:

[image]

```
$(".div2" ).droppable({
        accept: '.div1',
        tolerance: 'touch',
        drop: function(){ 
                        alert('dropped');
        }   
});
```

So, basically when *div1* touches *div2* , drop event should be triggered.

[image]

But the above case does not trigger the drop event.

The only case (shown below) that triggers the drop event in macs safari is when the draggable div *div1* completely passes the droppable div *div2*. i just dont know why??

[image]

> **Versions used:**
>
> ```
> jQuery: 1.7.2
> jQuery UI: 1.8.18
> Safari(mac): 5.1.5
> ```
>
> **update:**
>
> I tried other options of tolerance. Both '*touch*' and '*intersect*' do
>   not work as desired. But '*pointer*' works perfectly fine.
>
> Is there any other way i could achieve the functionality of 'tolerance:touch'? I am thinking of detecting collision between 2 divs and then apply the corresponding logic.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: A brief explanation in question is required, but faulty code that shows the live version of issue is really helpful - and it will make people understand you better - in the future try giving us the link to jsfiddle.net with your problem as example.

Comment: I had the same problem with 'touch', so I made a work around too. There is a JQuery extension by Brandon Aaron (http://brandonaaron.net) to detect collisions between DOM Elements (strictly speaking one element and a JQuery set). I now use a number of copies of this script on a website I am currently developing; the original script, one that detects whether whether the first element is wholly contained by a member of the set, and finally a copy that checks whether element A is within x number of pixels of a member of the set. Try playing with the plugin - any questions? Please ask :)

Comment: i had to also then develop a collision algorithm of my own to satisfy the above condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try add `position: absolute !important;` to the element. That's the solution I found to this problem. Otherwise you can try create a parent div for the draggable / droppable div.