# jQuery draggable clone - safari issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have a issue with dragging and dropping element within the Safari 8.0.4 on Mac. In all other browsers that I tested on Mac and Win everything works fine except in this one.

I have a draggable element with clone helper and containment set to 'document', and iFrameFix to true. When I remove this clone helper  line everything works fine, but when the helper is enabled, element can be dropped only if the top of the dragged element is inside the droppable area.

On droppable element i have tolerance set to touch but that's ignored in this case with clone helper.

The same situation as here:

[jQuery UI: Droppable ('drop' event, tolerance: touch )  bug in safari (mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104732/jquery-ui-droppable-drop-event-tolerance-touch-bug-in-safari-mac)

Any hint?

My page is included in iframe btw, don't know if that's important or not.

Comment: Just an update, I just confirm that this is issue just on mac version, windows version works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the element CSS as:

```
position: absolute !important;
```

It may be the missing piece. ;)